# How To: Leverage Browser Caching for some file Only

Tags: caching

I want to leverage browser caching for only some files, not all,
because my CSS and JS change very frequently. So I just want to cache some files only.

Comment: Which browser? And is it on a website you're hosting or what? Please provide more details. [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ AgataB I want to do it for chrome, Yes I hosted this site already. Actually i have different type of page in my website each having different css and javascript. And one of my page is taking a long time time to load. and every 10 sec this page get reloaded to check for any new update.so thats the problem,I dont want to reload all css and javascript of this page on every 10 sec. Thats why want to leverage Browser Caching to increase my page speed and also to optimize my page for SEO.And as i frequently change my css & Js of other page,so dont want to store all Css file in cache memory.